# Acceder datos JSON (PHP, AJAX)

Tags: php, ajax, json

Tengo el siguiente código el cual me hace la consulta de manera correcta en la base de datos:

```
<?php
$serverName = "SERVIDORSQL";
$connectionInfo = array(
    "Database" => "bd_test",
    "UID" => "supervisor",
    "PWD" => "supervisor",
    "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
$modelo = $_POST['codigo_sel'];

if ($conn === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors() , true));
}
else {
    echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}

$sql_consulta_query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql_consulta);

if (($sql_consulta_query = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT CNOMBREPRODUCTO
     FROM bd_test WHERE CCODIGOPRODUCTO = '$modelo' ")) !== false) {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql_consulta_query)) {
        $codigo_modelo[] = $row;
    }
}

echo json_encode($codigo_modelo);
```

Obtengo como resultado el siguiente JSON

```
[{"0":"CJ688TGBL","CNOMBREPRODUCTO":"CJ688TGBL"}]
```

Quiero acceder a los datos desde esta función, pero aun sin exito.

```
$('.autocompletarCodigo').focusout(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/inv/php/auto-modelo-other.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            codigo_sel: $('.autocompletarCodigo').val()
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#modelo1.autocompletarModelo').val(data);
    });

});
```

Ya intente varias combinaciones en el .val(data) pero sin éxito no eh podido acceder a los datos.

Quedo en espera de sus comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo guardes tus datos en un arreglo, en mi caso lo llame response, dentro de este arreglo guarde otro mas llmado datos, una vez que los arreglos estan llenos, uso json_encode pasando como parametro el arreglo response, asi cuando el servidor devuelva respuesta, devuelves el json reultante, en jquery lo manipulas dentro de de "success " recorriendolo con un each o simplemente imprimes el json en consola ´para ver los resultados.

php:

```
//como devolver la respuesta a la peticion ajax
    header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
    http_response_code(200);
    echo json_encode($response);
```

jquery:

```
success: function(response) {
                $.each(response.datos, function(index, value) {

                //accion
               });
                console.log(response);

            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los valores del objeto `data` usa:

```
console.log(data[0].CNOMBREPRODUCTO);
// Resultado: "CJ688TGBL"

console.log(data[0][0]);
// Resultado: "CJ688TGBL"
```

Puedes cambiar la siguiente línea de código para colocar el valor en el campo de texto:

```
$('#modelo1.autocompletarModelo').val(data[0].CNOMBR‌​EPRODUCTO);
```

o con Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('modelo1').value = data[0].CNOMBR‌​EPRODUCTO;
```

Comment: ¿Quedaria de esta manera la sintaxis?

$('#modelo1.autocompletarModelo').console.log(data[0].CNOMBREPRODUCTO);

Comment: @JulioMartinez si. ¿qué tipo de campo es `#modelo1.autocompletarModelo`?

Comment: mira, es muy sencillo, no te estreces con el ajax, simplemente accede al dato que necesitas desde php y despues de que tengas el dato que necesitas, ya lo envias por medio del json al ajax.

Comment: otra cosa....esta sintaxis $('#modelo1.autocompletarModelo').console.log(data[0].CNOMBR‌​EPRODUCTO) no te va a funcionar ya que el console.log(es para verlo en la consola entonces no seria logico que le des un ID al console.log seria algo redundante, es como si le dijeras muestrame pantalla/consola .-. ¿ves? no tiene sentido logico. Saludos

Comment: @Mauricio es un campo de texto de un formulario, esta de la siguiente manera :  "<input type="text" class="form-control autocompletarModelo" id="modelo1" name="n_modelo[]" maxlength="20" placeholder="ZZZ-XXXXX" /> "

Comment: @JulioMartinez, he editado mi respuesta.

Comment: @Mauricio gracias por la atenta respuesta, ya estuve probando y revisando en el navegador y no me arroja ningún error, pero tampoco me posiciona el dato en el campo de texto. Es algo raro, le daré otra revisión al código por si existe algún error en el formulario .